# Given a dataframe with 3 columns, return a list of lists of all the unique values of 'C', for each distinct pair of 'A' and 'B'

Tags: python, pandas, string, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
             foo      bar     baz
0   1234_312_GCD     1234     312
1   1234_312_GCD     1234     312
2   1234_312_GCD     1234     312
3   1234_312_GCD     1234     312
4   1234_312_GCD     1234     312
5   0777_666_lcm     0777     666
6   0777_666_lcm     0777     666
7   0777_666_lcm     0777     666
8   0777_666_lcm     0777     666
9   0777_666_lcm     0777     666
10  1234_312_lcm     1234     312
11  1234_312_lcm     1234     312
12  1234_312_lcm     1234     312
13  0777_666_GCD     0777     666
14  0777_666_GCD     0777     666
15  0777_666_GCD     0777     666
16  0777_666_GCD     0777     666
```

I want to return a list of lists, where each list contains all the distinct values of `foo`
corresponding to a pair of distinct values of `bar` and `baz`. For the example dataframe, this would be a list of two lists, each containing two strings:

```
foo_list = [['1234_312_GCD', '1234_312_lcm'], [0777_666_lcm', '0777_666_GCD']]
```

Comment: You can get the column you want with `df.group_by(['A', 'B']).agg(pl.col('C').unique())` and then just turn `C` into a list.

Comment: This is continuation of the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just groupby `bar` and `baz`, take the unique values of each `foo` group and then convert the resultant series of arrays into a list of lists:

```
out = list(map(list, df.groupby(['bar', 'baz'])['foo'].unique()))
```

Output:

```
[['0777_666_lcm', '0777_666_GCD'], ['1234_312_GCD', '1234_312_lcm']]
```

Note to get your exact result specified in the question, you'll need to turn off sorting in the groupby:

```
out = list(map(list, df.groupby(['bar', 'baz'], sort=False)['foo'].unique()))
```

Output:

```
[['1234_312_GCD', '1234_312_lcm'], ['0777_666_lcm', '0777_666_GCD']]
```

Comment: Great! Instead of `map(list(..)`, it also works like this: `list(df.groupby(['phi_des', 'mu_des'])['master'].unique().apply(list))`. I guess `apply(list)` does the same job as `map(list(...`.

Comment: Yeah, `apply` and `map` are doing the same thing. It would be interesting to compare performance. If I get a spare moment...

Comment: that would be great!!!

Comment: Maybe this week you'll find that spare moment :-)

Comment: @DeltaIV I finally got around to this, tried `map(list(..))`, `apply(list)` and `apply(np.ndarray.tolist)`. What I found was that `map(list(..))` and `apply(np.ndarray.tolist)` had similar timings, while `apply(list)` was about 2x slower than them.

Answer (score 0):

```
res_list = [group['foo'].unique().tolist() for _, group in df.groupby(['bar', 'baz'])]
```

Grouping together columns 'bar' and 'baz', and then collected the unique values.